# jQuery - Stopping a background function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a task running in the background that presents a new div with CSS3 animations every time the user scrolls down. I am using this code:

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
         // scrolling downwards
         hypeDocument.showNextScene(hypeDocument.kSceneTransitionPushBottomToTop, 1.1)    
         } else {
         hypeDocument.showPreviousScene(hypeDocument.kSceneTransitionPushTopToBottom, 1.1)
         }
    position = scroll;
});
```

But I would like to stop this task from running with a new function. Is there any way I could create a function to 'kill' all jQuery tasks?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's not a "task", it's an event handler. Just set a global flag and have the code in the handler run only when the flag is clear.

Comment: Or even better, make your code reusable, declare/assign the handler function, and detach scroll event from `window` when needed.

Comment: @pointy could you point me in the right direction? I'm very new to jQuery

Comment: @dwinnbrown or even you can **.unbind('scroll').bind('scroll',function(){})** try this

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of jQuery we can use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function for removing an event binding. Example is shown below.

Event handlers attached with `.bind()` can be removed with `.unbind()`. (As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` and `.off()` methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log('Scrolled');
  $('#scrollPos').text($(this).scrollTop())
})

$('#stopFunc').click(removeScrollBinding);

function removeScrollBinding() {
  $(window).off('scroll');
}
```

```css
#scrollPos{
   position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="stopFunc">Stop Scroll Function</button><div id="scrollPos"></div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Call the function `removeScrollBinding()` in order to stop the binding.